# Error in Angular 12 project while consuming angular library developed using angular 9

Tags: angular, angular12

I am working on Angular 12.x project, trying to consume angular library developed using angular 9.1.2 version.

I am getting errors like below on build:

```
Error: node_modules/@my-lib/lib/customlib-utils.module.d.ts:5:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/project/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵNgModuleDefWithMeta'.

5     static ɵmod: i0.ɵɵNgModuleDefWithMeta<customlibUtilsModule, never, [typeof i1.CommonModule, typeof i2.HttpClientModule], never>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/@my-lib/lib/services/customlib-utils-service.d.ts:23:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/project/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDef'.

23     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDef<customlibUtilsService, never>;
```

Comment: You can try to run ngcc in your terminal at the root of your project

Comment: I have Tried that but no luck